# What is the smallest number of times that you need to lift the pencil to draw a graph?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms

he problem : Is it possible to draw a given graph without lifting pencil from the paper, however I want to know the least number of pencil lifting when the graph is not Eulerian, is there a math formula for that?

[image]

[image]

regarding second image, it's not eulerian , and the least number of pen lifting is 1 , however how to know using math formula .

Comment: Eulerian graphs have an Eulerian cycle, but not having one doesn't prevent you from drawing them without lifting the pen. The second graph doesn't have an Eulerian cycle, but it does have an Eulerian path and therefore, you can drawing without lifting your pen.

Comment: @logarithm  . i know the second graph does not have eulerian cycle or even it's not semi eulerian , but my question how many edges do i need to add or remove to make semi eulerian or full eulerian so i can draw without lifting the pen . is there a general formula to know from number of odd and even verticies ?  cause i tried to write program for that but it was very slow that's why i am looking to math formula .

Comment: It is still not clear what you want. You keep equating existence of Eulerian *cycle* with being able to draw it without lifting the pen. But they are not the same thing. You can draw the second graph without lifting the pen (or repeating edges) by just following its Eulerian *path*. So, if you only care about drawing without lifting the pen, for the second graph you don't need to do any change. However, if your question were that you do want to have an Eulerian cycle, then you do need to modify the second graph.

Comment: the main point in my question how many time i need to lift the pencil or the pen while drawing the graph ? , i need mathematical formula for e.g i thinked in this formula  ( # of odds vertices / 2 ) -1 to get the number of lifting of pen , for example if i used this formula on second graph i will get one lifting happen while drawing , but my formula does not work in all instances or in all cases . @logarithm  , i am looking for help in the formula thank you .

Comment: Again, you can draw the second graph without lifting the pen. Start from the vertex of degree 1, go up along its only edge, and then travel the remaining quadrilateral part of the graph by going around it, for example counterclockwise. In general connected graphs with exactly two vertices of odd degree will have an Eulerian path like this, which means that you will be able to draw them without lifting your pen or repeating edges.

Comment: @logarithm ,  my question is not to check if the graph eulerian or semi-eulerian  , my question is to check if  i tried to draw continuous line on graph , how many times do i need to lift the pen or pencil while drawing , when the graph is not eulerain or semi-eulearian ,

Comment: Ok, read what I have said. You clearly haven't.

Comment: You two are talking past each other. The *second graph* is semi-Eulerian, and doesn't require lifting the pencil even once. The *third graph*, which is the graph in the *second image*, is not semi-Eulerian,and does require lifting the pencil. Also, I will edit the title, because it's misleading. (The answer to the question in the original title is "always $0$".)

Answer (score 2):

For any connected graph, the formula is
$$
   \max\left\{0, \frac{\text{(# of odd vertices)}}{2}-1\right\}.
$$
I'm including the $\max\{0, -\}$ to take Eulerian graphs into account, which have $0$ odd vertices and can be drawn without lifting the pencil at all.

To see that the formula works in the other cases, start with any connected but non-Eulerian graph, split up the odd vertices into pairs, and for all but one of the pairs, add a new edge between them.

(This may create a multigraph if the vertices were already adjacent, but that's fine.)

The new graph is, in your terminology, semi-Eulerian: it is connected with only two odd vertices, and therefore it has an Eulerian path. The new graph can be drawn without lifting the pencil even once, by following that path.

Following the same path, but skipping the edges we added, gives a way to draw the old graph. Every time we get to one of the edges we added (which don't exist in the original graph), we lift our pencil at one of the endpoints of the fake edge, and put it back down at the other endpoint. If there are $k$ odd vertices, there are $\frac k2$ pairs, so there are $\frac k2-1$ fake edges, and so we lift the pencil $\frac k2 - 1$ times.

We can't do better. Whenever the pencil passes through a vertex normally, it traces two of the edges out of the vertex - so if the vertex is odd, this won't take care of all of its edges. Therefore any odd vertex has to be the start of the path, the end of the path, a place where we lifted the pencil, or a place where we put the pencil back down. If we lift the pencil $\ell$ times, we can only deal with $2\ell+2$ odd vertices.

---

If the graph is not connected, then we can use the formula above over each connected component, add up the results, and finally add $$(\text{# of connected components})-1,$$ since of course we will have to lift the pencil to go from one connected component to the next.